# When does Python require parentheses around "not x"?

Tags: python

I get the following result in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. Why do the parentheses make a difference?

```
>>> True == (not False)
True
>>> True == not False
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    True == not False
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

> ...
>
> `not` has a lower priority than non-Boolean operators, so `not a == b` is interpreted as `not (a == b)`, and `a == not b` is a syntax error.

Comment: As I commented in the dup, I don't think it's due to operator precedence. Compare `2**-1`.

Comment: Operator precedence can't be the explanation. If that were the case, there would be an ambiguity. There is only one way to parse `True == not False` and Python can't do it because it is missing the expected grammar rule as Armali's answer on the dup explains.